# Chosen , I cant use search with var

Tags: jquery, search, jquery-chosen

I´m using a form and a field with chosen, in the chosen search i want to put the search taken from other textarea:

Temp is the var tha i want to use for search in chosen

```
var temp=document.forms.maintenance_product_texts.valueToLocate.value;
```

But this dont works, I need help

```
$('.chosen').chosen({ width: "500px" });
$("#popupSelect").trigger('chosen:open');


$('#popupSelect').val(temp).trigger('chosen:updated');
```

Comment: This example run if a Val is in the select, but I want pass a variable to make search, no a value.

Comment: Can you add your HTML too?